# How can you mock a class that takes arguments in its constructor?

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit

Have just spent a few hours trying to mock a service class that calls a third party API, and the fix I found was to remove the arguments from its constructor.

I would like to understand why this is the case, and if there's a way to get around it, so my service class can still take constructor arguments AND be mocked?

I set the up mock in my tests like this:

```php
$this->mock(App\Libraries\APICaller::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
  $mock->shouldReceive('callTheApi')->once();
});
```

I've also tried setting up the mock like this, to the same effect:

```php
$this->instance(
    APICaller::class,
    Mockery::mock(APICaller::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('callTheApi')->once();
    })
);
```

I *call* the class in the controller I'm testing like this, making sure to get the instance of the class through Laravel rather than using `new APICaller($args)`:

```php
$APICaller = App::make(APICaller::class, ['apiToCall' => $api]);
// ...
$APICaller->callTheApi();
```

(I have also tried `App::makeWith()` with the same results.

That throws this error in my test:

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException: Method callTheApi(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0_App_Libraries_APICaller should be called exactly 1 times but called 0 times.
```

If I add log statements to the mocked method, I can also see them being logged, so the mock isn't being used at all.

However the test passes (and log statements don't run) if I instantiate the mocked class without arguments and just hard code them directly into the constructor (something I don't really want to do, because I want to instantiate the class with different arguments depending on where it is being used). This works:

```php
$APICaller = App::make(APICaller::class);
```

I'm currently using Laravel 9. Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two ways around this.

First (simplest) is to call `app()->offsetSet()` after creating the mock:

```php
$mock = $this->mock(APICaller::class, function (MockInterface $mock) {
    $mock
        ->shouldReceive('callTheAPI')
        ->once();
});

app()->offsetSet(APICaller::class, $mock);
```

Found that here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/25041#issuecomment-445479867

The other way is to change how the mock is created, doing this instead:

```php
$mock = Mockery::mock(APICaller::class)->makePartial();

$mock->shouldReceive('callTheApi')->once();

$this->app->bind(APICaller::class, function () use ($mock) {
    return $mock;
});
```

Found that one here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/19450#issuecomment-451549582

Both of these mean the class being mocked can still be instantiated with arguments, and the `->shouldReceive()` test is correctly triggered.